# How to resolve volley library in androidx?

Tags: android, android-volley, androidx, resolve, dependency-resolver

Volley library is not being resolved. I have checked android jetpack, but the search was futile. Could you please help me resolve this dependency? Has someone recently built a project using volley?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Try including some source code to explain the issue. I've given an answer to understand your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use volley like the below example?

```
 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```